# Chome Extension - Check API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying write an extension which runs whenever you visit a steam profile. The extension gets the profile's ID, and should then call my database to check if they are a scammer, trusted middleman, etc.
I have written a version which works perfectly, however it has been denied by Google:

> We routinely review items in the Chrome Web Store for compliance with
>   our Program policies to ensure a safe and trusted experience for our
>   users. Per our policies, where possible, make as much of your code
>   visible in the package as you can. If some of your app's logic is
>   hidden and it appears to be suspicious, we may remove it.
>
> Your item was found to have requested/fetched one or more external
>   scripts. An example of one such instance in your item was found in
>   check.js line 18.
>
> To have your item reinstated, please make any necessary changes to
>   ensure:
>
> All of the files and code are included in the item’s package. Avoid
>   requesting or executing remotely hosted code (including by referencing
>   remote javascript files or executing code obtained by XHR requests).

The line of code in question is this:

```
fetch("https://www.example.com/check.php?id=" + id)
```

Is there a better/correct way of doing this that would be allowed in a web extension?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that URL returns a non-executable response then the rejection reason is likely something else, because otherwise it would mean the reviewers are mistaken/dumb. What do you do with the response? Do you use eval or put it into a script tag? This is what's important.

Comment: The URL literally returns "0|0|0|0", though any of the 0's could be a 1...

Comment: `var source = text;
var sourceSplit = source.split('|');

if (sourceSplit[0] == '1') div.children[0].appendChild(developerImg);
if (sourceSplit[1] == '1') div.children[0].appendChild(trustedImg);
if (sourceSplit[2] == '1') div.children[0].appendChild(donatorImg);
if (sourceSplit[3] == '1') div.children[0].appendChild(scammerImg);
`

Comment: Well, if you don't use eval or put the response into a script element then you are a victim of a robotic/dumb reviewer so I guess just try resubmitting until it succeeds.

Comment: So it's just an automatic process that blocked it, and if I resubmit it it'll be manually reviewed? This is my first chrome extension, new to this

Comment: I don't see any other options. A knowledgeable developer wouldn't nitpick this line, right?

Comment: It does seem dumb to me, the only thing I could see them being "worried" about is I get information from the page and send it, that information being the steam ID.

Comment: @wOxxOm you were right, after disputing it, it was approved. But any update to the extension (even a screenshot update) requires me to re-dispute it...